# Work done in carnot cycle, where has my reasoning gone wrong here?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am trying to find an expression for work done in a carnot cycle as part of a question in my problem sheet.

I tried to start with the statement that in one cycle $\Delta U = 0$.
Thus, by the first law:

$\Delta Q+\Delta W=0$

$TdS = - \Delta W$.

But the change in entropy for any reversible cycle is $0$.

So that means $dS = 0$, implying that $\Delta W = 0$ which is not true.

What was wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Delta Q=\int{TdS}$, not TdS or even $T\Delta S$.  What makes you think that if $\Delta S=\int{dS}=0$, it follows mathematically that $\int{TdS}=0$.  It does not.

Comment: The OP was obviously not thinking what you say in your second sentence, as it seems like they weren't aware of your first sentence.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens I wonder exactly what the OP was thinking.  What is your opinion?

Comment: I'm not sure. But you seem to think they have used a line of reasoning I cannot find in the post.

Comment: This does answer my question. I just thought it followed that if $\Delta S = 0, T * \Delta S = 0$. I forgot to keep in mind that it might work for a sum, but an integral doesn't work exactly the same as the temperature weighting affects the summation.

Comment: @VishalJain Technically is it true that $\Delta S=0\to T\,\Delta S=0$. You are right to focus on the sums and integrals though.

Comment: @AaronStevens. You really didn't mean that $\Delta S = 0$ implies that $T\Delta S = 0$, did you?

Comment: Yes I did. If I multiply two numbers together and one of the numbers is $0$, then the product is equal to $0$. This doesn't say anything about $\int T\,\text dS$ though.

Comment: @AaronStevens. Ha Ha.  Got me.  Good one.

Answer (score 0):

But the Carnot cycle uses reservoirs at two different temperatures. When plotted in a T-S graph, it gives a rectangle corresponding to the two reversible isothermal steps and two reversible adiabatic (isentropic) steps.

Let's label the following :
$$ 1 \rightarrow 2 \text{ : Reversible Isothermal Expansion of Gas at $T_H$, from $S_1$ to $S_2$}$$
$$ 2 \rightarrow 3 \text{ : Reversible Adiabatic Expansion of Gas at $S_2$, from $T_H$ to $T_C$}$$
$$ 3 \rightarrow 4 \text{ : Reversible Isothermal Compression of Gas at $T_C$, from $S_2$ to $S_1$}$$
$$ 4 \rightarrow 1 \text{ : Reversible Adiabatic Compression of Gas at $S_1$, from $T_C$ to $T_H$}$$

Therefore, for a reversible Carnot heat engine,
$$Q_{supplied} = \oint T dS = \int_1^2 T_H dS + \int_3^4 T_C dS =(T_H - T_C)(S_2 - S_1)= W_{\text{done by the gas}}$$